# Indoor tilapia aquaponic farm in condo/apartment?

Tags: food, aquaponics, apartment

Are there problems with an aquaponic tilapia farm for a condo/apartment living space? Is this sustainable and safe?

I'm thinking there might be problems with humidity/mold and possible water pump noise?

Answer (score 1):

I have been wanting to make a aquaponic system as well. The biggest problem, for me, is that I live in Denmark and I am sure that I can't get enough sunlight all year to keep the ecosystem running.

I would think the same problem, not enough light, might be present in an apartment.